# Mongoose greater than and equal

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

how to get greater than or equal integer values from Mongodb using Mongoose?
assume that below list

```
list = [134,56,89,89,90,200] //Marks field
```

want to get values equal or greater than 89, result set must be `[89,90,200]`
in my query I was able to get values greater than 89, I want to get it with 89

```
let x = 89;
query.find().where('marks').gt(x);
```

Comment: You could maintain the query structure you already have by simply swapping out [`gt`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-gt) with [`gte`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-gte).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't know what version of mongodb you are using. But this is what available in the latest releases.

`$gte` selects the documents where the value of the field is greater than or equal to (i.e. >=) a specified value

```
query.find( { marks: { $gte: 89} } )
```

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/)

Comment: The question is concerning Mongoose, hence the syntax that does not work with native MongoDB (`.gt(x)`). There are two solutions in this case, actually - either using direct query, as you wrote, or using Mongoose to advantage and using chained Query API: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
.gte(upperlimit)
```

for greater than equal to and

```
.lte(lowerlimit)
```

for less than equal to.

Remember **upperlimit** and **lowerlimit** should be numeric.

Answer (score 1):

`Query.prototype.gt` method is the same as using "greater than" operator.

In your case, you have to use `gte` method that returns exactly what you need - results that are greater or equal to given value:

```
let x = 89;
query.find()
  .where('marks')
  .gte(x)
  .exec();
```

Also, as another answer mentioned, you can always use native MongoDB operator `$gte`, however Mongoose offers more intuitive approach with its chaining Query API, as above.

Also, if you're using Mongoose with Promises or `async/await`, don't forget to add
`exec()` at the end - this will convert thenable-compatible Query result to a fully featured Promise, e.g.:

```
let x = 89;
find().where('marks').gte(x).exec()
  .then(() => {/* rest of handling*/})
  .catch(() => { /* error handling */});
```

The same code using `async/await`:

```
async function getResultsGreaterThan(x) {
  const results = await find().where('marks').gte(x).exec();
  console.log(results);
  return results;
}

getResultsGreaterThan(89);
```

More on Mongoose chainable Query API can be found in rather solid official docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html